# How to map URL to specific controller's method in Spring MVC using XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I know it's possible to do it with `@RequestMapping` *annotation* but is there way to do it in my *XML* dispatcher servlet settings file? I tried using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`:

*mvc-dispathcer-servlet.xml*

```
...

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/users">userController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

...
```

But as far as I understand there is no way to map URL to certain controller's method with `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`. Is there way to do it in *XML* settings file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

Using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, you can only map URLs to a single controller. This makes sense: before Java-5 and annotations, the only way to make a URL mapping was to use `HandlerMapping`, and the only way to make a controller was to create a class that extented `AbstractController`. Such controllers could only handle the URL they were configured with. At the time, URL mapping was class oriented and not method oriented.

Since Java 5, Spring MVC added a lot of annotations like `@RequestMapping` allowing for method-oriented URL mapping but they didn't backport this to the XML configuration.

There is actually a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5757)  for exactly this feature, that remains unresolved at time of this writing (with a fix version of 4.3 Backlog).